# allow typescript compilation with no unused variable rule

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm using these rules in tsconfig in order to highlight unused variables and imports in vscode.

```
 "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */

 "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
```

However I would like these rules not to block compilation.
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript will never block the compilation, as long as the syntax is valid.
What you see are just "warnings", your javascript files are emitted.

Comment: Not true. Here's what I'm getting in a TSX file: `Failed to compile. TS6133: 'e' is declared but its value is never read.`

Comment: Can you give a proper example?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark them as `false`. So the unused variables appear as warnings. Then when you fix that you can set those variables to `true`